# unwanted horizontal line from svg mask

Tags: css, d3.js, svg

I'm rendering a line using an SVG mask and gradient, similar to how Github renders sparklines for [their "year of activity" charts](https://github.com/greeninfo-network/) that are displayed when viewing and organization's list of repositories.

For some reason when the width of the SVG is a certain value, a horizontal line appears at the top of the lines:

[image: svg mask with unwanted horizontal line]

The line appears to correspond to the SVG group element that houses a rectangle which is applied a mask and a gradient fill:

[image: svg mask with group element highlighted]

However, resizing the SVG to a different width results in the line not displaying:

[image: svg mask path with no bug]

Here is the markup for an example SVG:

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<svg width="281" height="50">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient-36" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#f03b20"></stop>
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#feb24c"></stop>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#ffeda0"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <mask id="mask-36" x="0" y="0" width="281" height="46">
      <path fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke="#ffeda0" d="M0,46C2.7238899312070046,46,5.447779862414009,46,8.171669793621014,46C10.811353450072962,46,13.451037106524913,46,16.09072076297686,46C18.814610694183866,46,21.53850062539087,46,24.262390556597875,46C26.98628048780488,46,29.71017041901188,46,32.434060350218886,46C34.89434803001876,46,37.35463570981863,46,39.81492338961851,46C42.53515217844486,46,45.25538096727121,34.5,47.97560975609756,34.5C50.611632270168855,34.5,53.247654784240154,46,55.88367729831145,46C58.60756722951845,46,61.331457160725456,34.5,64.05534709193246,34.5C66.69136960600376,34.5,69.32739212007505,46,71.96341463414635,46C74.68730456535334,46,77.41119449656036,46,80.13508442776735,46C82.85897435897435,46,85.58286429018136,46,88.30675422138836,46C90.94277673545966,46,93.57879924953095,34.5,96.21482176360225,34.5C98.93871169480926,34.5,101.66260162601625,46,104.38649155722327,46C107.02617521367522,46,109.66585887012717,46,112.30554252657912,46C115.02943245778611,46,117.75332238899313,46,120.47721232020012,46C123.20110225140714,46,125.92499218261413,34.5,128.64888211382114,34.5C131.19703721075672,34.5,133.74519230769232,46,136.2933474046279,46C139.01357619345424,46,141.7338049822806,46,144.45403377110694,46C147.09005628517824,46,149.7260787992495,46,152.3621013133208,46C155.08599124452783,46,157.80988117573483,46,160.53377110694186,46C163.16979362101316,46,165.80581613508443,46,168.44183864915573,46C171.16572858036272,46,173.88961851156972,46,176.61350844277672,46C179.33739837398372,46,182.06128830519074,46,184.78517823639774,46C187.42120075046904,46,190.05722326454034,46,192.69324577861164,46C195.41713570981864,46,198.14102564102564,46,200.86491557223263,46C203.50459922868458,46,206.14428288513653,46,208.78396654158848,46C211.50785647279548,46,214.2317464040025,46,216.9556363352095,46C219.6795262664165,46,222.4034161976235,46,225.1273061288305,46C227.58759380863037,46,230.04788148843028,46,232.50816916823015,46C235.2283979570565,46,237.94862674588282,46,240.66885553470917,46C243.30487804878047,46,245.94090056285177,46,248.57692307692307,46C251.30081300813006,46,254.0247029393371,46,256.7485928705441,46C259.38461538461536,46,262.0206378986867,34.5,264.65666041275796,34.5C267.38055034396496,34.5,270.10444027517195,46,272.82833020637895,46C275.55222013758595,46,278.276110068793,46,281,46">
      </path>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <g transform="translate(0, 2)">
    <rect x="0" y="-2" width="281" height="46" style="stroke: none; fill: url(&quot;#gradient-36&quot;); mask: url(&quot;#mask-36&quot;);">
    </rect>
  </g>
</svg>
```

And here is a link to live code showing the bug: 
https://bl.ocks.org/clhenrick/ed231b1ba92c87f82529c153e7c77a4e/4954afeeccc9b2d61547e08bb901a8ae23c32c83

Here is a link to an example using the same technique with **no bug**, just a different size width for the SVG, mask, rect and different sized path:
https://bl.ocks.org/clhenrick/e0b06bbb361780f818993e956dccc5d8/d1fcd24b4df5571ed7069f4a45ed9932a48d74c2

Furthermore, with the buggy example when I move the path element out of the mask and into the group element, the path looks correct:
https://bl.ocks.org/clhenrick/b1ac9490a5708afbcb3ef7f93bb45b3a/5df5bd70333da98d866e7f59e3dd74060ff87474

I'm not sure why this happens at certain SVG widths or SVG path sizes and not at others.

Comment: don't put screenshot, put code instead

Comment: @TemaniAfif updated to include actual markup

Comment: Can't see the issue with your first link in either Chrome or Safari.

Comment: @jcaron I'm on a Mac, viewing with Chrome and it's visible to me.

Comment: Note that running the code within the question above does not show the bug. The external link does show it though.

Comment: @clhenrick check my answer again, i found some intresting things

Answer (score 1):

Am not sure what is causing the issue but here is a work around to avoid it. The idea is to hide this line by changing the position of the `rect` (its y value).

So here is the buggy SVG :

```css
body {
background:black;
}
```

```html
<svg width="281" height="50">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient-36" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#f03b20"></stop>
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#feb24c"></stop>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#ffeda0"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <mask id="mask-36" x="0" y="0" width="281" height="46">
      <path fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke="#ffeda0" d="M0,46C2.7238899312070046,46,5.447779862414009,46,8.171669793621014,46C10.811353450072962,46,13.451037106524913,46,16.09072076297686,46C18.814610694183866,46,21.53850062539087,46,24.262390556597875,46C26.98628048780488,46,29.71017041901188,46,32.434060350218886,46C34.89434803001876,46,37.35463570981863,46,39.81492338961851,46C42.53515217844486,46,45.25538096727121,34.5,47.97560975609756,34.5C50.611632270168855,34.5,53.247654784240154,46,55.88367729831145,46C58.60756722951845,46,61.331457160725456,34.5,64.05534709193246,34.5C66.69136960600376,34.5,69.32739212007505,46,71.96341463414635,46C74.68730456535334,46,77.41119449656036,46,80.13508442776735,46C82.85897435897435,46,85.58286429018136,46,88.30675422138836,46C90.94277673545966,46,93.57879924953095,34.5,96.21482176360225,34.5C98.93871169480926,34.5,101.66260162601625,46,104.38649155722327,46C107.02617521367522,46,109.66585887012717,46,112.30554252657912,46C115.02943245778611,46,117.75332238899313,46,120.47721232020012,46C123.20110225140714,46,125.92499218261413,34.5,128.64888211382114,34.5C131.19703721075672,34.5,133.74519230769232,46,136.2933474046279,46C139.01357619345424,46,141.7338049822806,46,144.45403377110694,46C147.09005628517824,46,149.7260787992495,46,152.3621013133208,46C155.08599124452783,46,157.80988117573483,46,160.53377110694186,46C163.16979362101316,46,165.80581613508443,46,168.44183864915573,46C171.16572858036272,46,173.88961851156972,46,176.61350844277672,46C179.33739837398372,46,182.06128830519074,46,184.78517823639774,46C187.42120075046904,46,190.05722326454034,46,192.69324577861164,46C195.41713570981864,46,198.14102564102564,46,200.86491557223263,46C203.50459922868458,46,206.14428288513653,46,208.78396654158848,46C211.50785647279548,46,214.2317464040025,46,216.9556363352095,46C219.6795262664165,46,222.4034161976235,46,225.1273061288305,46C227.58759380863037,46,230.04788148843028,46,232.50816916823015,46C235.2283979570565,46,237.94862674588282,46,240.66885553470917,46C243.30487804878047,46,245.94090056285177,46,248.57692307692307,46C251.30081300813006,46,254.0247029393371,46,256.7485928705441,46C259.38461538461536,46,262.0206378986867,34.5,264.65666041275796,34.5C267.38055034396496,34.5,270.10444027517195,46,272.82833020637895,46C275.55222013758595,46,278.276110068793,46,281,46">
      </path>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <g transform="translate(0, 2)">
    <rect x="0" y="-2" width="281" height="46" style="stroke: none; fill: url(&quot;#gradient-36&quot;); mask: url(&quot;#mask-36&quot;);">
    </rect>
  </g>
  </svg>
```

And if you change the y from -2 to 34 the line will disappear like this :

```css
body {
background:black;
}
```

```html
<svg width="281" height="50">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient-36" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#f03b20"></stop>
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#feb24c"></stop>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#ffeda0"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <mask id="mask-36" x="0" y="0" width="281" height="46">
      <path fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke="#ffeda0" d="M0,46C2.7238899312070046,46,5.447779862414009,46,8.171669793621014,46C10.811353450072962,46,13.451037106524913,46,16.09072076297686,46C18.814610694183866,46,21.53850062539087,46,24.262390556597875,46C26.98628048780488,46,29.71017041901188,46,32.434060350218886,46C34.89434803001876,46,37.35463570981863,46,39.81492338961851,46C42.53515217844486,46,45.25538096727121,34.5,47.97560975609756,34.5C50.611632270168855,34.5,53.247654784240154,46,55.88367729831145,46C58.60756722951845,46,61.331457160725456,34.5,64.05534709193246,34.5C66.69136960600376,34.5,69.32739212007505,46,71.96341463414635,46C74.68730456535334,46,77.41119449656036,46,80.13508442776735,46C82.85897435897435,46,85.58286429018136,46,88.30675422138836,46C90.94277673545966,46,93.57879924953095,34.5,96.21482176360225,34.5C98.93871169480926,34.5,101.66260162601625,46,104.38649155722327,46C107.02617521367522,46,109.66585887012717,46,112.30554252657912,46C115.02943245778611,46,117.75332238899313,46,120.47721232020012,46C123.20110225140714,46,125.92499218261413,34.5,128.64888211382114,34.5C131.19703721075672,34.5,133.74519230769232,46,136.2933474046279,46C139.01357619345424,46,141.7338049822806,46,144.45403377110694,46C147.09005628517824,46,149.7260787992495,46,152.3621013133208,46C155.08599124452783,46,157.80988117573483,46,160.53377110694186,46C163.16979362101316,46,165.80581613508443,46,168.44183864915573,46C171.16572858036272,46,173.88961851156972,46,176.61350844277672,46C179.33739837398372,46,182.06128830519074,46,184.78517823639774,46C187.42120075046904,46,190.05722326454034,46,192.69324577861164,46C195.41713570981864,46,198.14102564102564,46,200.86491557223263,46C203.50459922868458,46,206.14428288513653,46,208.78396654158848,46C211.50785647279548,46,214.2317464040025,46,216.9556363352095,46C219.6795262664165,46,222.4034161976235,46,225.1273061288305,46C227.58759380863037,46,230.04788148843028,46,232.50816916823015,46C235.2283979570565,46,237.94862674588282,46,240.66885553470917,46C243.30487804878047,46,245.94090056285177,46,248.57692307692307,46C251.30081300813006,46,254.0247029393371,46,256.7485928705441,46C259.38461538461536,46,262.0206378986867,34.5,264.65666041275796,34.5C267.38055034396496,34.5,270.10444027517195,46,272.82833020637895,46C275.55222013758595,46,278.276110068793,46,281,46">
      </path>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <g transform="translate(0, 2)">
    <rect x="0" y="34" width="281" height="46" style="stroke: none; fill: url(&quot;#gradient-36&quot;); mask: url(&quot;#mask-36&quot;);">
    </rect>
  </g>
  </svg>
```

This will of course affect the fill you are applying as it's a linear background. So you may change it to adjust the color as you need.

---

I made more tests trying to point out what can be the cause of the issue. I tried to eliminate some part of the SVG (like the linear-gradien) and to change some values and here is what i got :

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

svg {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<svg width="281" height="50">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask-36" x="0" y="0" width="281" height="46">
      <path fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke="#ffeda0" d="M0,46C2.7238899312070046,46,5.447779862414009,46,8.171669793621014,46C10.811353450072962,46,13.451037106524913,46,16.09072076297686,46C18.814610694183866,46,21.53850062539087,46,24.262390556597875,46C26.98628048780488,46,29.71017041901188,46,32.434060350218886,46C34.89434803001876,46,37.35463570981863,46,39.81492338961851,46C42.53515217844486,46,45.25538096727121,34.5,47.97560975609756,34.5C50.611632270168855,34.5,53.247654784240154,46,55.88367729831145,46C58.60756722951845,46,61.331457160725456,34.5,64.05534709193246,34.5C66.69136960600376,34.5,69.32739212007505,46,71.96341463414635,46C74.68730456535334,46,77.41119449656036,46,80.13508442776735,46C82.85897435897435,46,85.58286429018136,46,88.30675422138836,46C90.94277673545966,46,93.57879924953095,34.5,96.21482176360225,34.5C98.93871169480926,34.5,101.66260162601625,46,104.38649155722327,46C107.02617521367522,46,109.66585887012717,46,112.30554252657912,46C115.02943245778611,46,117.75332238899313,46,120.47721232020012,46C123.20110225140714,46,125.92499218261413,34.5,128.64888211382114,34.5C131.19703721075672,34.5,133.74519230769232,46,136.2933474046279,46C139.01357619345424,46,141.7338049822806,46,144.45403377110694,46C147.09005628517824,46,149.7260787992495,46,152.3621013133208,46C155.08599124452783,46,157.80988117573483,46,160.53377110694186,46C163.16979362101316,46,165.80581613508443,46,168.44183864915573,46C171.16572858036272,46,173.88961851156972,46,176.61350844277672,46C179.33739837398372,46,182.06128830519074,46,184.78517823639774,46C187.42120075046904,46,190.05722326454034,46,192.69324577861164,46C195.41713570981864,46,198.14102564102564,46,200.86491557223263,46C203.50459922868458,46,206.14428288513653,46,208.78396654158848,46C211.50785647279548,46,214.2317464040025,46,216.9556363352095,46C219.6795262664165,46,222.4034161976235,46,225.1273061288305,46C227.58759380863037,46,230.04788148843028,46,232.50816916823015,46C235.2283979570565,46,237.94862674588282,46,240.66885553470917,46C243.30487804878047,46,245.94090056285177,46,248.57692307692307,46C251.30081300813006,46,254.0247029393371,46,256.7485928705441,46C259.38461538461536,46,262.0206378986867,34.5,264.65666041275796,34.5C267.38055034396496,34.5,270.10444027517195,46,272.82833020637895,46C275.55222013758595,46,278.276110068793,46,281,46">
      </path>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <g transform="translate(0, 2)">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="281" height="46" style="stroke: none; fill:red; mask: url(&quot;#mask-36&quot;);">
    </rect>
  </g>
  </svg>
<svg width="281" height="50">
  
  <g transform="translate(0, 2)">
       <path fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke="#ffeda0" d="M0,46C2.7238899312070046,46,5.447779862414009,46,8.171669793621014,46C10.811353450072962,46,13.451037106524913,46,16.09072076297686,46C18.814610694183866,46,21.53850062539087,46,24.262390556597875,46C26.98628048780488,46,29.71017041901188,46,32.434060350218886,46C34.89434803001876,46,37.35463570981863,46,39.81492338961851,46C42.53515217844486,46,45.25538096727121,34.5,47.97560975609756,34.5C50.611632270168855,34.5,53.247654784240154,46,55.88367729831145,46C58.60756722951845,46,61.331457160725456,34.5,64.05534709193246,34.5C66.69136960600376,34.5,69.32739212007505,46,71.96341463414635,46C74.68730456535334,46,77.41119449656036,46,80.13508442776735,46C82.85897435897435,46,85.58286429018136,46,88.30675422138836,46C90.94277673545966,46,93.57879924953095,34.5,96.21482176360225,34.5C98.93871169480926,34.5,101.66260162601625,46,104.38649155722327,46C107.02617521367522,46,109.66585887012717,46,112.30554252657912,46C115.02943245778611,46,117.75332238899313,46,120.47721232020012,46C123.20110225140714,46,125.92499218261413,34.5,128.64888211382114,34.5C131.19703721075672,34.5,133.74519230769232,46,136.2933474046279,46C139.01357619345424,46,141.7338049822806,46,144.45403377110694,46C147.09005628517824,46,149.7260787992495,46,152.3621013133208,46C155.08599124452783,46,157.80988117573483,46,160.53377110694186,46C163.16979362101316,46,165.80581613508443,46,168.44183864915573,46C171.16572858036272,46,173.88961851156972,46,176.61350844277672,46C179.33739837398372,46,182.06128830519074,46,184.78517823639774,46C187.42120075046904,46,190.05722326454034,46,192.69324577861164,46C195.41713570981864,46,198.14102564102564,46,200.86491557223263,46C203.50459922868458,46,206.14428288513653,46,208.78396654158848,46C211.50785647279548,46,214.2317464040025,46,216.9556363352095,46C219.6795262664165,46,222.4034161976235,46,225.1273061288305,46C227.58759380863037,46,230.04788148843028,46,232.50816916823015,46C235.2283979570565,46,237.94862674588282,46,240.66885553470917,46C243.30487804878047,46,245.94090056285177,46,248.57692307692307,46C251.30081300813006,46,254.0247029393371,46,256.7485928705441,46C259.38461538461536,46,262.0206378986867,34.5,264.65666041275796,34.5C267.38055034396496,34.5,270.10444027517195,46,272.82833020637895,46C275.55222013758595,46,278.276110068793,46,281,46">
      </path>
  </g>
  </svg>

<svg width="281" height="50">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask-35" x="0" y="0" width="281" height="46">
      <path fill="none" stroke-width="3" stroke="#ffeda0" d="M0,46C2.7238899312070046,46,5.447779862414009,46,8.171669793621014,46C10.811353450072962,46,13.451037106524913,46,16.09072076297686,46C18.814610694183866,46,21.53850062539087,46,24.262390556597875,46C26.98628048780488,46,29.71017041901188,46,32.434060350218886,46C34.89434803001876,46,37.35463570981863,46,39.81492338961851,46C42.53515217844486,46,45.25538096727121,34.5,47.97560975609756,34.5C50.611632270168855,34.5,53.247654784240154,46,55.88367729831145,46C58.60756722951845,46,61.331457160725456,34.5,64.05534709193246,34.5C66.69136960600376,34.5,69.32739212007505,46,71.96341463414635,46C74.68730456535334,46,77.41119449656036,46,80.13508442776735,46C82.85897435897435,46,85.58286429018136,46,88.30675422138836,46C90.94277673545966,46,93.57879924953095,34.5,96.21482176360225,34.5C98.93871169480926,34.5,101.66260162601625,46,104.38649155722327,46C107.02617521367522,46,109.66585887012717,46,112.30554252657912,46C115.02943245778611,46,117.75332238899313,46,120.47721232020012,46C123.20110225140714,46,125.92499218261413,34.5,128.64888211382114,34.5C131.19703721075672,34.5,133.74519230769232,46,136.2933474046279,46C139.01357619345424,46,141.7338049822806,46,144.45403377110694,46C147.09005628517824,46,149.7260787992495,46,152.3621013133208,46C155.08599124452783,46,157.80988117573483,46,160.53377110694186,46C163.16979362101316,46,165.80581613508443,46,168.44183864915573,46C171.16572858036272,46,173.88961851156972,46,176.61350844277672,46C179.33739837398372,46,182.06128830519074,46,184.78517823639774,46C187.42120075046904,46,190.05722326454034,46,192.69324577861164,46C195.41713570981864,46,198.14102564102564,46,200.86491557223263,46C203.50459922868458,46,206.14428288513653,46,208.78396654158848,46C211.50785647279548,46,214.2317464040025,46,216.9556363352095,46C219.6795262664165,46,222.4034161976235,46,225.1273061288305,46C227.58759380863037,46,230.04788148843028,46,232.50816916823015,46C235.2283979570565,46,237.94862674588282,46,240.66885553470917,46C243.30487804878047,46,245.94090056285177,46,248.57692307692307,46C251.30081300813006,46,254.0247029393371,46,256.7485928705441,46C259.38461538461536,46,262.0206378986867,34.5,264.65666041275796,34.5C267.38055034396496,34.5,270.10444027517195,46,272.82833020637895,46C275.55222013758595,46,278.276110068793,46,281,46">
      </path>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <g transform="translate(0, 2)">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="281" height="46" style="stroke: none; fill:red; mask: url(&quot;#mask-35&quot;);">
    </rect>
   </g>
  </svg>
```

The first one is the buggy and when i tried to add the path directly into the SVG it works fine (the second one). In the third one i changed the value of stroke in the path to make it 3 and the line disappeared.

I can conclude that it's because you are using **the path as a mask**. It can be a bug related to some browser and not a bug with your code. In this case you can simply consider using the path directly as an element (and you have a lot of possiblities to color it using gradient) or use my **trick** in order to hide the bug.

Comment: Yes I suspect it has something to do with the "g" element as well, as in dev tools you can see that the unwanted horizontal line goes along the top of the g element. However, the g element is necessary so that the path doesn't get clipped off when the path is near the top of the SVG container.

Comment: @clhenrick no it's not the g .. i updated my answer again, try and see. I think it's the browser and the drawing stuffs

Comment: that's very odd!

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me why github do their sparklines graphs using that complicated arrangement of rects, masks, and transforms.  It appears it may be triggering a bug in Chrome.

Have you considered just simplifying the graph?  Just use the sparkline path on its own, and apply the gradient directly to it?

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<svg width="281" height="50">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient-36" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#f03b20"></stop>
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#feb24c"></stop>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#ffeda0"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <path fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke="url(#gradient-36)" d="M0,46C2.7238899312070046,46,5.447779862414009,46,8.171669793621014,46C10.811353450072962,46,13.451037106524913,46,16.09072076297686,46C18.814610694183866,46,21.53850062539087,46,24.262390556597875,46C26.98628048780488,46,29.71017041901188,46,32.434060350218886,46C34.89434803001876,46,37.35463570981863,46,39.81492338961851,46C42.53515217844486,46,45.25538096727121,34.5,47.97560975609756,34.5C50.611632270168855,34.5,53.247654784240154,46,55.88367729831145,46C58.60756722951845,46,61.331457160725456,34.5,64.05534709193246,34.5C66.69136960600376,34.5,69.32739212007505,46,71.96341463414635,46C74.68730456535334,46,77.41119449656036,46,80.13508442776735,46C82.85897435897435,46,85.58286429018136,46,88.30675422138836,46C90.94277673545966,46,93.57879924953095,34.5,96.21482176360225,34.5C98.93871169480926,34.5,101.66260162601625,46,104.38649155722327,46C107.02617521367522,46,109.66585887012717,46,112.30554252657912,46C115.02943245778611,46,117.75332238899313,46,120.47721232020012,46C123.20110225140714,46,125.92499218261413,34.5,128.64888211382114,34.5C131.19703721075672,34.5,133.74519230769232,46,136.2933474046279,46C139.01357619345424,46,141.7338049822806,46,144.45403377110694,46C147.09005628517824,46,149.7260787992495,46,152.3621013133208,46C155.08599124452783,46,157.80988117573483,46,160.53377110694186,46C163.16979362101316,46,165.80581613508443,46,168.44183864915573,46C171.16572858036272,46,173.88961851156972,46,176.61350844277672,46C179.33739837398372,46,182.06128830519074,46,184.78517823639774,46C187.42120075046904,46,190.05722326454034,46,192.69324577861164,46C195.41713570981864,46,198.14102564102564,46,200.86491557223263,46C203.50459922868458,46,206.14428288513653,46,208.78396654158848,46C211.50785647279548,46,214.2317464040025,46,216.9556363352095,46C219.6795262664165,46,222.4034161976235,46,225.1273061288305,46C227.58759380863037,46,230.04788148843028,46,232.50816916823015,46C235.2283979570565,46,237.94862674588282,46,240.66885553470917,46C243.30487804878047,46,245.94090056285177,46,248.57692307692307,46C251.30081300813006,46,254.0247029393371,46,256.7485928705441,46C259.38461538461536,46,262.0206378986867,34.5,264.65666041275796,34.5C267.38055034396496,34.5,270.10444027517195,46,272.82833020637895,46C275.55222013758595,46,278.276110068793,46,281,46">
  </path>
</svg>
```

Comment: My goal is to replicate the style Github uses, so using the SVG mask and gradient is desired.

Comment: I’ve also noticed the bug in other browsers such as Firefox